# Create foreach loop from JSON array

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm having problem with creating a foreach loop out of a JSON, I can't get the values out of the array correct, what am I doing wrong?

JSON:

```
[
{"Pages":{
         "name":"Name 1",
         "id":"3342939832994"
         }
},
{"Pages":{
         "name":"Name 2",
         "id":"289051164453763"
         }
}
]
```

PHP:

```
    $json = $_POST['Publish'];

    $json = $json->Pages

    foreach($json as $key => $items) {

    $id = $items->id;     
    $name = $items->id;     

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to `json_decode` the data. What's the next question?

Comment: Voting to close because "get the values out of the array correct" is not a problem description.

Comment: Thanks, I tried json_decode, but then the string gives med "null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['Publish']);
```

json_decode - Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Comment: obligatory docs: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Also, depending, you may want to set `$assoc = true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($_POST['Publish'], true);

foreach($array as $item) {
    $id= $item['Pages']['id'];
    $name = $item['Pages']['name'];
    echo "id: $id <br/> name: $name <br/><br/>";
}

?>
```